# How to do a JavaScript calculation on page load?

Tags: javascript, html

I built a financing calculator, and I have pre-checked values in the HTML. Once is for a 60 month financing term, and the other is for a 10% down payment.

**Link to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/financing-calculator-jk1rj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).**

When the page loads up, the calculator hasn't calculated the values yet because in order to do so, the user has to select values and then hit Calculate.

Is there a way for one page load, to load up the total calculated values for the selected values of 60 and 10%?

Thank you in advance!

### index.js

```
// Define product price

const productPrice = 105000;

// Append product price to DOM

const productPriceID = document.getElementById("product-price");
productPriceID.innerHTML = productPrice.toLocaleString();

// Grab the id's of the main product price, down payment, total, per month and button for DOM appending

const downPaymentValue = document.getElementById("down-payment-value");
const totalValue = document.getElementById("total-value");
const perMonthValue = document.getElementById("per-month-value");
const calculateBtn = document.getElementById("calculate");

///////// Calculations

calculateBtn.addEventListener("click", calculate);

function calculate() {
  // Grab the value of the month selected
  const monthSelected = document.querySelector('input[name="month"]:checked')
    .value;
  // Grab the value of the down payment percentage selected
  const percentageSelected = document.querySelector(
    'input[name="percent"]:checked'
  ).value;
  // Calculate down payment percentage based on main price
  const totalDownPayment = productPrice * percentageSelected;
  // Calculate the total
  const totalPrice = productPrice - totalDownPayment;
  // Calculate the per month
  const perMonth = totalPrice / monthSelected;
  // Convert to text with options argument to specify number of decimals
  const totalDownPaymentStr = totalDownPayment.toLocaleString(
    navigator.language,
    { minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }
  );
  const totalPriceStr = totalPrice.toLocaleString(navigator.language, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  });
  const perMonthStr = perMonth.toLocaleString(navigator.language, {
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  });
  // Append down payment to DOM
  downPaymentValue.innerHTML =
    "<sup>$</sup>" + totalDownPaymentStr.toLocaleString();
  downPaymentValue.parentNode.appendChild(downPaymentValue);
  // Append total to DOM
  totalValue.innerHTML = "<sup>$</sup>" + totalPriceStr.toLocaleString();
  totalValue.parentNode.appendChild(totalValue);
  // Append per month to DOM
  perMonthValue.innerHTML = "<sup>$</sup>" + perMonthStr.toLocaleString();
  perMonthValue.parentNode.appendChild(perMonthValue);
}

///////// Accessibility

// Grab all labels

const allLabels = document.querySelectorAll("label");

// On enter, select only the ones that are selected

allLabels.forEach(label => label.addEventListener("keyup", onEnter));

function onEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode === 13) {
    this.click();
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like at the end of your index.js file you could just call your `calculate` method (i.e. `calculate();`). I tried that in your sandbox and it appeared to work.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel haha, wow. This totally do it. Thanks a lot Daniel!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the 'calculate()' function after defining the global variables as 60% and 10% values are pre-checked.

Link to [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/financing-calculator-m152g?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line right before `calculate` function:

```
window.onload = calculate();
```

Comment: `window.onload` can only take one function, so this line will replace anything already attached to `window.onload`. It is safer to use `window.addEventListener("load", calculate);`.